# PHP retrieve pictures from server

Tags: php, mysql

So here is the set up:

I am running on a local host environment (all permissions are fine). The project I am working on has to retrieve photos from the server and output them in a table. I do this by saving image paths on a mysql DB (I know mysql is deprecated...) and outputting them via PHP like so,

```
    <div class='images'>
    <?php
    $error = "";
    $query = "SELECT imagepath FROM stories "; //replace image path with user
    if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0) $error='no images found';
    else {
        $query2 = "SELECT imagepath FROM stories "; //replace image path with user
        $result = queryMysql($query2); 
        $array = array(); 
        echo "<table id='imagebox'>
        <tr>";
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
            $array[] = $rows; 
        }
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++ ) {
            echo "<td><img id='photo' src='$array[$j]' height='100' width='100'></td>"; 
            if (($j %3) == 0 ){
                echo "</tr><tr>"; 
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
    }
    ?>
```

In short, the output works. I get the table I want, but the image doesn't display (I see the box where it should be with the broken image symbol). Its not a problem with the stored link, because I have tested it. Help is appreciated. (PS ignore the comments in the code, they have nothing to do with my predicament).

Comment: did you check the image url is fine ?

Comment: That means the path to the image is wrong. Are you using absolute or relative URLs? A sample of your output might help.

Comment: var_dump($rows; );  ?

Comment: yes, if i do something like this echo "<img src='$array[4]' />"; it outputs the fifth element in the array, so it seems as if the link works        EDIT: it output the *picture* that the fifth url in the array leads to.

Comment: I figured it out. I ran this command to see what was actually stored in the array and got... 

echo "$array[1]"; *outputs* Array

so something is wrong with the loop. 

thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is either:
1. The url of the image is not in the database or
2. The image data is in the database, not the image path

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that on the server you are storing relative links instead of absolute links, ie,  /image1.jpg instead of www.yourserver.com/image1.jpg.

Comment: Your example isn't very clear. If the actual image is at `www.yourserver.com/image1.jpg` then setting the source to `/image1.jpg` would still work.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

in database imagepath  juste the name of file

```
<div class='images'>
<?php
$error = "";
$query = "SELECT imagepath FROM stories "; //replace image path with user
if (mysql_num_rows(queryMysql($query)) == 0) $error='no images found';
else {
    $query2 = "SELECT imagepath FROM stories "; //replace image path with user
    $result = queryMysql($query2); 
    $array = array(); 
    echo "<table id='imagebox'>
    <tr>";
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        $array[] = $rows; 
    }
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($array); $j++ ) {
        echo "<td><img id='photo' src='./images/$array[$j]' height='100' width='100'></td>"; 
        if (($j %3) == 0 ){
            echo "</tr><tr>"; 
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: i write this without test sorry. what error you get !!